# открытие вк и facebook(android)

Tags: java, android, facebook, вконтакте

Как сделать так: К примеру есть надпись: "Мы вконтакте" и "Мы в facebook", при нажатии на "Мы вконтакте" приложение сразу предлагает открыть ссылку приложением вк(конечно если он установлен на телефоне), аналогично "Мы в facebook"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаем интент как для открытия обычной ссылки. Если вам нужно именно предложить открыть им, то делать ничего не надо, оно будет в списке выбора приложений. Если же нужно в первую очередь открыть им, то ищем среди приложений, которыми можно открыть эту ссылку, подходящее и ставим его.

```
private static final String VK_APP_PACKAGE_ID = "com.vkontakte.android";
private static final String FACEBOOK_APP_PACKAGE_ID = "com.facebook.katana";

public static void openLink(Activity activity, String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    if (resInfo.isEmpty()) return;

    for (ResolveInfo info: resInfo) {
        if (info.activityInfo == null) continue;
        if (VK_APP_PACKAGE_ID.equals(info.activityInfo.packageName)
                || FACEBOOK_APP_PACKAGE_ID.equals(info.activityInfo.packageName)
                ) {
            intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
            break;
        }
    }
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}

Иcпользоваение в активности:
openLink(this, "http://vk.com/id1");
openLink(this, "https://www.facebook.com/groups/StackOverFlow");
```

Comment: Может знаете, как с помощью интентов запостить фотографию на стену в ФБ и ВК?